# user position by data from accelerometer

Tags: ios, swift, position, accelerometer

The task is to get user position by data from accelerometer relative to initial position. I have two arrays: integratedValues(for saving velocities) and integratedValues2(for positions) and add zero initial conditions to these arrays at first. Then I receive coremotion data and pass useracceleration vector into integrating functions two times to get position:

---

**Main part looks like this:**

```
 if(self.onButClickedFirstTime) {
                                self.initialFrame = dmData.attitude
                                self.onButClickedFirstTime = false
                                self.currentRotationMatrix = dmData.attitude.rotationMatrix
                                self.curAttitude = dmData.attitude
                            }

                            var calculatedAcceleration = self.multiplyMatrixOnVector(rotMat:
                                dmData.attitude.rotationMatrix, acceleration: [Double](arrayLiteral: dmData.userAcceleration.x,
                                                                                       dmData.userAcceleration.y,
                                                                                       dmData.userAcceleration.z)
                            )

                            for index in 0 ..< 3{
                                if(calculatedAcceleration[index] > -0.1 && calculatedAcceleration[index] < 0.1) {
                                    calculatedAcceleration[index] = 0.0
                                }

                            }

                            self.calculatedAccelerations.append(calculatedAcceleration)
                            if(self.calculatedAccelerations.count >= 2) {
                                //receive velocity in integratedValues array
                                self.integratedValues.append(self.trapezoid())
                                //receive position in integratedValues array
                                self.integratedValues2.append(self.trapezoid2())
                            }
                            else {
                                //receive velocity in integratedValues array
                                self.integratedValues.append(self.rectangle())
                                //receive position in integratedValues array
                                self.integratedValues2.append(self.rectangle2())
                            }
```

**integrating functions**

```
func trapezoid() -> [Double]{
    let step = 0.01
    var innerArray:[Double] = [Double].init(repeating: 0, count: 3)

    for k in 0..<3 {

        innerArray[k] =  integratedValues[integratedValues.count-1][k] + (step/2.0)*(calculatedAccelerations[calculatedAccelerations.count-2][k] + calculatedAccelerations[calculatedAccelerations.count-1][k])
    }
    return innerArray
}

func rectangle() -> [Double]{
    let step:Double = 0.01
    var temporary:[Double] = [Double].init(repeating: 0, count: 3)
    for k in 0..<3 {

        temporary[k] =  integratedValues[integratedValues.count-1][k] + (step*calculatedAccelerations[calculatedAccelerations.count-1][k])
    }
    return temporary
}
```

It doesn't work. I get coordinate values(x,y or z) that separately increase or decrease all the time after I moved my phone for the first time. For example, x and y increase, z decreases permanently:

x:  2.45885665392312 
y:  12.0701960347246 
z:  -7.70172802770194

x:  2.46064406756483 
y:  12.0903748004539 
z:  -7.71571460119331

x:  2.46241602875171 
y:  12.1105587446889 
z:  -7.72968592982189

x:  2.46418465445463 
y:  12.1307452781769 
z:  -7.74362066535627

x:  2.4659587846542 
y:  12.1509318116648 
z:  -7.75751655337187

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution. I have exactly the same issue.